# How should I "merge" multiple Dictionaries into an "aggregate" in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, hashtable

I have the following scenario :

The function `GetDict()` returns a `Dictionary<double, double>` object and is called in a loop some number of times (this number being specified by the user). The Dictionary returned is always guaranteed to contain the same set of keys (I am assuming this for simplicity for now).

My goal is to ultimately get an average of all the values returned for each key :

```
public Dictionary<double, double> CalculateAveragePerKey(int N)
{
    var aggregateDict = new Dictionary<double, double>();

    for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        var returnedDict = GetDict();
        // aggregateDict -- how to calculate an average of values for each key?
    }

    return aggregateDict;
}

public Dictionary<double, double> GetDict()
{
    var newDict = new Dictionary<double, double>();
    // populate the newDict, always guaranteed (assumed for simplicity)
    // to contain the same set of keys ...
    return newDict;
}
```

So, if N=3 and within the loop, the Dictionary returned contains for the key `10.0` the values `1.0`, `2.3` and `3.0`, at the end `aggregateDict` should have the value `2.1` for the key `10.0`.

If this is not the best data structure or methodology to solve this kind of problem, I can definitely refactor my code to use some other data structure or methodology. I'm just looking for the most efficient way.

Comment: `double` is a really bad type to use for a key to a dictionary, since floating point precision errors often result in numbers that you would expect to be equal being not equal, combined with the fact that hash based structures don't' really handle fuzzy equality.

Comment: I didn't think of that. How else can I solve this problem then? Should I use a double dimensional array to store the key value pairs? (I could also cast my keys to ints in GetDict() during preprocessing, but is there a better option?)

Comment: Is this homework? Have you tried to solve the problem yourself yet?

Comment: You should probably use `decimal` instead of `double` if these numbers are representations of exact base ten numbers.

Comment: @MgSam, no, this is part of a larger program I'm writing that runs an algorithm a number of times on some dataset and combines the results in this manner. I originally stored everything in double dimensional arrays (instead of dicts) and looped over them to calculate the average, but since my data is in the form of key value pairs, I was hoping that this kind of an approach might turn out to be more efficient perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code to compute average in two steps:

- When you call `GetDict()` in a loop, go through its keys, and add values to values of the `aggregateDict`
- When the loop is over, go through the values again, and divide them by `N`.

You could also divide values of `GetDict()` by `N` inside the loop, depending on the distribution of values that you get in `GetDict()`.

You can also do this with LINQ without using a loop, like this:

```
var avg = Enumerable
    .Range(0, N)
    .SelectMany(n => GetDict())
    .GroupBy(p => p.Key)
    .ToDictionary(
            g => g.Key
        ,   g => g.Sum(p => p.Value) / g.Count()
        );
```

Note that you need to be very careful when using `double` as a dictionary key, because floating-point types are inherently imprecise. As the result, you may see two very close numbers map to different dictionary keys.

Comment: Thanks, I am considering rewriting some logic to cast my keys to ints. A follow-up question - my dataset consists of about 30k key-value pairs. Is LINQ the most efficient way? I had originally used the loop-over-all-values approach you mentioned, but was wondering if it was efficient due to the large size of my dataset.

Comment: @ubuntunoob If the number `N` is ten or more, go with your approach (see the top of the answer) because it uses less memory. In terms of timing, it does not matter if you go with LINQ or not, because either way the timing would be on the order of `K*N`, where `K` is the number of keys, and `N` is the number of repetitions. LINQ would tend to use more memory, though, so for high `N`s you may be better off with a loop.

Comment: For now N is 3 or 4. I will try the LINQ approach, thanks. I've read a bit about PLINQ but haven't used it. Would it help here?

Comment: @ubuntunoob Assuming that it's OK to call `GetDict()` concurrently, PLINQ might be faster. I would definitely give it a try.